# Access column of target table after calling relationship - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables as follows

Base Table

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string
```

Target Table

```
roles
    id - integer
    name - string
```

Pivot Table

```
role_user
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer
```

Many to many relationship is exist between `users` and `roles` table

If I want all the users with role_id of '1' so I can simply do this as

```
$result = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q){
   $q->where('roles.id', 1);
});
```

but I also want the role name correspond to role_id '1' which is `name` column of `roles` table.

Is there any way I can append role name into `$result` collection.

Comment: Add a `with` clause `->with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->where('roles.id', 1)->select('id','name');
}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to use `map()`. The eager loading (`with()`) is very important though, to prevent the N+1 issue in your query. Without eager loading one additional query would be executed for each user in your result.

```php
$result = App\User::query()
    ->with([
        'roles' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereId(1);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
        $q->whereId(1);
    })
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($user) {
        $user['name'] = $user->roles->first()->name;

        return $user;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **Eagerload** the relationship to get the column you want:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function ($q){
            $q->where('roles.id', 1);
        })->with(['roles' => function ($q){
        $q->select('name')->where('roles.id', 1);
          }])->get();
```

Comment: it just returns all the users instead of users with role_id  = 1

Comment: @FahadShaikh Edited answer.

Comment: updated answer returns the correct number of result but still `name` column from target table is not included in collection. The output is same as one returned by query in question